# How to find out the size of the Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed

Is there a way I can quickly find out the size (i.e. the number of the available keys) in a Kafka topic partition? The topic has log compaction enabled. The reason why I need to do this is to verify that the compaction did make the partitions smaller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48931055/10504469