# How to check Kafka topic memory usage?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way to check the current total memory usage of all the messages in topic?

We have a retention policy set to a max number of bytes and we're trying to check if we are actually hitting max or not. We see that some messages are missing from the topic. We believe it might be because we hit the max size.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473670/see-size-of-kafka-topics-in-bytes ?

Comment: I was trying to find a jmx pattern that you can use to continuously track topic size. I haven't found it yet.